# Path of a file in the user directory from root directory

Tags: python-2.7, paths

Following is the directory structure for a text file textfile.txt ,what will be the file path for the text file for an python script readtext.py which is in the in the root direcory. The python file runs from the shell. The code in the python file is as follows.

```
with open(<file_path>,'r') as infile:
    print infile.read()
```

The directory structure

```
/
    root
        readtext.py

    home
        user1
            textfile.txt
```

Comment: `/home/user1/textfile.txt`

Answer (score 1):

There are two ways to specify a file path.

```
An absolute path, which always begins with the root folder

A relative path, which is relative to the program’s current working directory
```

There are also the dot (.) and dot-dot (..) folders. These are not real folders but special names that can be used in a path. A single period (“dot”) for a folder name is shorthand for “this directory.” Two periods (“dot-dot”) means “the parent folder.”

Understanding this gives you 2 answers.

Absolute path as mentioned by [PerlDuck comment:](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1045068/path-of-a-file-in-the-user-directory-from-root-directory/1045150#comment1704116_1045068)
 `/home/user1/textfile.txt`

And the relative path

`../home/user1/textfile.txt`

Personally in this case I would recommend the absolute path.

Recommended reading: https://automatetheboringstuff.com/chapter8/